# I can not deploy the audioplayers plugin in my project, I need to play two audios at the same time

Tags: flutter

```
I/OpenGLRenderer(19557): Davey! duration=713ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=139263631608286, Vsync=139264114941600, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=139264123639500, AnimationStart=139264123779136, PerformTraversalsStart=139264133089605, DrawStart=139264314444988, SyncQueued=139264317538791, SyncStart=139264317704884, IssueDrawCommandsStart=139264317940978, SwapBuffers=139264342826658, FrameCompleted=139264345146033, DequeueBufferDuration=22799000, QueueBufferDuration=452000, 
E/flutter (19557): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/audios/som_botao.mp3
E/flutter (19557): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
E/flutter (19557): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19557): #1      AudioCache._fetchAsset (package:abc_kids/audio_cache.dart:58:29)
E/flutter (19557): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19557): #2      AudioCache.fetchToMemory (package:abc_kids/audio_cache.dart:65:30)
E/flutter (19557): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19557): #3      AudioCache.load (package:abc_kids/audio_cache.dart:80:37)
E/flutter (19557): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19557): #4      AudioCache.play (package:abc_kids/audio_cache.dart:99:23)
E/flutter (19557): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19557): #5      _CardAprenderPronunciaState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:abc_kids/pages/card_aprender_pronuncia.dart:69:42)
E/flutter (19557): #6      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:635:14)
E/flutter (19557): #7      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:711:32)
E/flutter (19557): #8      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter (19557): #9      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:365:11)
E/flutter (19557): #10     TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:275:7)
E/flutter (19557): #11     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:455:9)
E/flutter (19557): #12     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:75:13)
E/flutter (19557): #13     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:102:11)
E/flutter (19557): #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
E/flutter (19557): #15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter (19557): #16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (19557): #17     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter (19557): #18     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (19557): #19     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13)
E/flutter (19557): #20     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter (19557): #21     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
E/flutter (19557): #22     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:250:10)
E/flutter (19557): #23     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:159:5)
E/flutter (19557):
```

Comment: Hi, Ruan. Welcome to Stack Overflow! The error message you posted says that it couldn't load the file "assets/audios/som_botao.mp3". Are you sure you put the audio file in place and added the asset folder reference in the pubspec.yaml?

Comment: yes, it is in the correct folder, however it cannot access this file, and sometimes it also pops up the error "he application may be doing too much work on its main thread"